# MATLAB Matrix Multiply Code efficiency

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am using MATLAB to prototype a few matrix multiply techniques and compare efficiency. Eventually, I will move the prototype codes to C. It is for a homework assignment where we need to write an efficient matrix multiply routine (by being aware of cache size, locality, etc.).

I am curious about the efficiency differences between these two very similar loops:

**Matrix Multiply Loop 1**
- sum over columns of A times elements of B -> column of C

```
function [C] = dgemm_naivepe( A,B,C,n )

for j=1:n
    tempcol=zeros(n,1);
    for k=1:n
        for i=1:n
            tempcol(i)=tempcol(i)+A(i+(k-1)*n)*B(k+(j-1)*n);
        end
    end
    for k=1:n
        C(k+(j-1)*n)=tempcol(k);
    end
end
```

end

**Matrix Multiply Loop 2**
- sum over columns of A times elements of B -> column of C

```
function [C] = dgemm_naivepe( A,B,C,n )

for j=1:n
    for k=1:n
        for i=1:n
            C(i+(j-1)*n)=C(i+(j-1)*n)+A(i+(k-1)*n)*B(k+(j-1)*n);
        end
    end
end

end
```

After several test runs of various matrix sizes, I found that **Loop 1** is faster than **Loop 2**. Could someone help me understand why this is?

edit: As you can see, the matrices are stored as 1D arrays in column major ordering.

Comment: How did you time it exactly? Also, why do you pass `C` as input? Its contents seem not be used in the function

Comment: You should read Golub & Van Loan (http://web.mit.edu/ehliu/Public/sclark/Golub%20G.H.,%20Van%20Loan%20C.F.-%20Matrix%20Computations.pdf).

Comment: @LuisMendo Using MATLAB's `tic`,`toc` utility

Comment: @EternusVia Using `tic`, `toc` is not very reliable. Better use `timeit`

Comment: How do you know that what is most efficient in Python will be most efficient in C? If your aim is to build an efficient C routine it'd be wise to to compare various C implementations.

Comment: You might want to take a look at these FEX submissions: [1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977) [2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37515). When timing performance it's best to mention your system parameters (at least: OS, CPU, MATLAB version) and the inputs you're using. When results are not reproducible, anybody can claim that whichever algorithms is faster _on their mahcine_ - which is not very helpful...